# Get file unit by name and vice versa in Fortran

Tags: string, io, fortran

Is there a way in Fortran 90 to get a file unit by name and file name by unit number? I know it will be expensive, but I have a lot of file names that I want to be able to re-access in a subroutine after they've been created..

Comment: Because the answer says both, I believe it is useful to have also both in the question. If you disagree, you can roll-back the edit.

Comment: Looks good to me, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A command like

```
inquire(unit=12, opened=openedq, file=name_of_file)
```

will return the name of the file connected to unit 12 to the character variable `name_of_file`. If there is no file connected to the unit `opened` will return `false`, otherwise `true`.  The command takes a variety of other optional arguments too.

To get the unit number of a file which is already attached use a variation on the preceding, like this

```
inquire(file='my_favourite_file.nuts', number=unknown_unit_number, opened=openedq)
```

Reference to your compiler documentation should explain all the variations that `inquire` supports.

Comment: I don't know what the unit number is (in your case 12), but I do know the name of the file that I want to open and write to (in your case name_of_file)... I created a temporary integer to open the unit, but lost it when leaving a subroutine. Is there any way that I can still access the file without the original unit number and just with the file name? Or do I have to save the unit number?...

Comment: You have to save the unit number, or use INQUIRE to get it again as Mark suggested.

Comment: Looks like outdated answer.  See the answer by Federico Perini below

Answer (score 4):

In order to get file information, you have to use the `INQUIRE` statement.

`UNIT` and `FILE` are both valid *input* options to the `INQUIRE` statement, but I am not sure if they can used for output (For example, gfortran 7.4.0 will complain that `INQUIRE statement at (1) cannot contain both FILE and UNIT specifiers`).

So, to get file name information from a unit number, use `NAME`, e.g.:

`inquire(unit=12, opened=openedq, NAME=name_of_file)`

To get unit number information, the previous example is valid:

`inquire(file='my_file', opened=openedq, NUMBER=file_unit)`