# How do we check filename of a given Fortran file unit in GDB?

Tags: file, fortran, gdb

Say I have opened a file in a Fortran code

```
OPEN(UNIT=5,FILE='filename',STATUS='old',ACTION='read')
```

and later in the code, I have

```
WRITE(5,*) 'something...'
```

When running in GDB and stop at the line `WRITE...`, how can I check what is the filename of `UNIT=5`?

**Edit**

The compiler I used is `ifort`. It turned out that in the code that I am reading, the unit=5 file stream is not opened, and the program just wrote to a file with the name `fort.5`.

Comment: Did you read up on INQUIRE ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Be sure to take the [tour] and read [ask]. Note that unit `5` is often pre-connected to standard input and it is advisable to open external files on different unit numbers (>10).

Comment: Sorry missed your gdb request. I will re-open, but be sure to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26020497/fortran-90-get-file-unit-by-name anyway.

Comment: The answer for GDB is almost surly bound to be compiler dependent. So you must tell us the name of your compiler, the version, and be sure to get a complicated answer. Otherwise it is very llikely not possible to answer.

Comment: It is fortran 90 compiled using `ifort` version 14.0.1 20131008. It would be easier if I can just look up the filename of the unit=5 in the gdb, instead of changing the code to `inquire` the filename every time I need it.